# Limit content size

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

Does anyone know how I can set a limit on the char length for posts when using the "content=yes" function?

I need something like excerpt_size but for the content, not excerpt. 
Before someone suggests using excerpt, it strips out the formatting and line breaks so I want to use the content output function but set a limit like you can with excerpt_size.
I hope that makes sense to you.

I don't mind hacking the php in the plugin if someone knows what I need to change in there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could enable links, images and other tags for use with the_excerpt. This might be the most simple solution, but it will apply to **all excerpts**:

```
<?php
function my_excerpt_custom($text) {
$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    $text = get_the_content('');
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text ); 
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $allowed_tags = '<a>,<p>,<img>';
    $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);

    $excerpt_word_count = 88; /*** MODIFY THIS. change the excerpt word count to any integer you like.***/
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count);

    // $excerpt_end = '[...]'; /*** MODIFY THIS. change the excerpt endind to something else.***/
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);
    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
        array_pop($words);
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
        $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
    } else {
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_excerpt_custom');
?>
```

I've added a few of the most likely tags from the code found here: [bac consulting website](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-preserve-html-tags-in-wordpress-excerpt-without-a-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'll try that out. Would this be added to one of the plugin files or to the functions.php file for the theme?

Comment: I'd add it to my functions.php file, but it might cause a conflict with one of your plug-ins. If it does dis-able the plug-in's one at a time to find the culprit.

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing, if you use the code above you should notice I commented out the line that starts $excerpt_end. I did this because the theme I was testing it on already had a function for this. If your excerpts don't have and ending you can delete the // to enable it.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll take a look at that when I run it tomorrow. Fingers crossed it wont take much to get it playing nice with everything else. It'll be nice when I can make my own themes and know how all these things work. By the way, is there a "Thank you" button or something on these forums?

Comment: There is an accept as answer and an up-vote button for correct answers. That's as good as a thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just cut off the content on any position: The break may occur inside of an element like `table`, `blockquote` or `pre`. The only way to do this per script: use a [DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), walk through the parsed document tree, count the characters in each element and stop if you are in a safe context. Very difficult.

The only safe way is to use `the_content()` and a [manually set](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) `<!--more-->` marker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the plugin allows you to set the char count for the excerpt, why can't you do that when using the "content=yes" setting?

Comment: Because content contains markup. You need to count just the visible characters.

Answer (score -1):

Go to wpcontent> plugins> list-category-posts> list_cat_posts.php

edit excerpt size to whatever.

```
                        'id' => '0',
                        'name' => '',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => 'desc',
                        'numberposts' => '50',
                        'date' => 'no',
                        'date_tag' => '',
                        'date_class' =>'',
                        'dateformat' => get_option('date_format'),
                        'author' => 'no',
                        'author_tag' =>'',
                        'author_class' => '',
                        'template' => 'default',
                        'excerpt' => 'yes',
                        **'excerpt_size' => '100',**
                        'excerpt_tag' =>'yes',
                        'excerpt_class' =>'',
                        'exclude' => '0',
                        'excludeposts' => '0',
                        'offset' => '2',
                        'tags' => '',
                        'content' => 'no',
                        'content_tag' => 'yes',
                        'content_class' => '',
                        'catlink' => 'no',
                        'catlink_tag' =>'',
                        'catlink_class' => '',
                        'comments' => 'no',
                        'comments_tag' => '',
                        'comments_class' => '',
                        'thumbnail' => '',
                        'thumbnail_size' => 'thumbnail',
                        'thumbnail_class' => '',
                        'title_tag' => '',
                        'title_class' => '',
                        'post_type' => '',
                        'post_parent' => 'no',
                        'class' => 'lcp_catlist',
                        'customfield_name' => '',
                        'customfield_value' =>'',
                        'customfield_display' =>'',
                        'taxonomy' => '',
                        'categorypage' => '',
                        'morelink' => '',
                        'morelink_class' => ''
```